# Convert varchar to datetime in sqlserver table

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In SQL Server I have a column called "dateCreation" defined as varchar(50) and I would like to convert it to datetime type. If I change the column's type to datetime with the MS SQL Server Management Studio I get the following warning:

```
'atPropostes' table
- Warning: Data might be lost converting column 'dateCreation' from 'varchar(50)'.
```

Then If I execute this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, dateCreation, 120) as dateCreation from atPropostes -- to convert it to Datetime
```

I get the following error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

What would be **the best way** to 
(1) change the column type to datetime and 
(2) convert all the registers from varchar(50) to Datetime type?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have values in your column that cannot be converted to `DATETIME`. Are you sure all values are valid dates, following the same format?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using SQL Server 2012

Try like this

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, dateCreation, 120) AS dateCreation
FROM atPropostes
```

Note: Please make sure that your date stored in varchar type have consistent date format. It should be something like yyyy-mm-dd or mm-dd-yyyy or.....

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2, TRY_CONVERT is not recognized. Thanks. But my question would be, do I have to first change the column type and then do the conversion or viceversa or all together in one action?